# Eclipse (with J2EE plugins) will not build class files to output directory

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-2, m2eclipse

I have had this issue with several versions of Eclipse.  In some scenarios, Eclipse will not output bytecode class files to the output directory.  I will do a build and a clean.  I am working with Tomcat server.  I stop the server and still Eclipse will not do a build.

My output directory: project/WebContent/WEB-INF/classes

Sometimes after doing so many builds and/or restarting my machine, I am able to build again to that directory.  Does any know what the problem is?

Also, what is the best way to create a bug report for this problem.

Version Info: Galileo
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Build id: 20100218-1602

Also, mvn m2eclipse plugin installed.

Comment: Getting any build errors? Can you show your pom?

Comment: the build and clean operations above - are these the Eclipse operations or m2eclipse operations?

Comment: build and clean operations are maven opperations.

Comment: *build* and *clean* are available as separate Eclipse tasks too! Right click on any project and you'll find 'build' [which is not linked to Maven]. and go to 'Project' menu item, there you'll find "clean" [which also, is not linked to Maven].

Answer (score 8):

This usually happens if, project build path is missing some required libraries. Also ensure, build automatically is checked [ Project > Build Automatically ]. Please post if you still face problem

Comment: @Ranta, I am having the same problem, all my source packages are copied over to metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/webapp but without any class files. Any ideas?

Comment: Check whether your source folder is configured and added to build path and output folders

Comment: Wow! I faced this problem like 30 mins, saw this post and thought: 'Ah, this can't be true'. I was so wrong! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. I had "Build Automatically" checked, and was expecting class file in my project/bin directory but it was empty. What worked for me was unchecking "Build Automatically" in Project menu, Project -> Clean and then do Project -> Build All. Now all .java files were compiled and I checked "Build Automatically" again.

Answer (score 0):

I have another simple question, but I don't know how to comment on the question directly without adding an answer.

Are you running Eclipse/m2eclipse on Windows? If so, you may be having issues with errors occurring during the "clean" lifecycle stage. If you add the following to the <profiles /> element in your ~/.m2/settings.xml, you should be able to avoid this type of build interruption:

`<profile>
        <id>windows-nocleanerrors</id>
        <activation>
            <os>
                <family>Windows</family>
            </os>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <maven.clean.failOnError>false</maven.clean.failOnError>
        </properties>
</profile>`

Comment: Use the "add comment" link under the question (and any comments).

Comment: I see the link under my answer, but not under the question. I must need a higher rep for adding comments to questions.

Comment: Interesting response.  I may check that out.